# The best way to remove parameters from an URL dynamically based on matching id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to dynamically remove `id` parameters from a URL based upon the id of the div that is clicked. The id's are separated By a capital Z. I basically need to write a check that matches the clicked div's `id` with the `id` in the URL. And then remove that parameter if it's clicked and reload the page with the URL that has the removed `id`.

Statically i've written some JQuery to remove it if only one `id` is available.

Here is an example url

http://example.com/cyegyufy-Z9c86uh9ozzpZ90a9emsjmdiZgjkgkjgkukZlkhlkhlklk

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
$('blah blah blah'). on('click', e=> {
    removeParam(e)
    console.log('has been clicked')
})

const removeParam =(e) => {
    var pathArray = window.location.href.split('-Z');
    var ArticlePillId = e.currentTarget.id
    if (pathArray[1] === ArticlePillId) {
        pathArray.splice(1)
    }
    console.log(pathArray)
    window.location.href = pathArray[0]
}
```

This reloads the page, with the exact URL but it's static.

Comment: "static" - what do you mean?

Comment: static meaning i know which id was clicked. I want to know how to do it without knowing which div the user is going to click

Comment: so like "go to url.com/articles-Zid " if I click on any article, but if that's the one I'm already looking at "go to url.com/articles" ?

Comment: Kind of.. If youre on url.com/articles-Zid and you click a div on the page for example that has an id that directly correlates with the ID in the url. When you click on that button it needs to reload the page removing that id from the url and reload the page. But their can be multiple buttons with different id's that are all in the url that can individually be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the pathname of the url on the fly based on click events on the articles. Be aware that by assigning/changing anything within `window.location` the page will automatically reload.

```
 document.querySelectorAll("article").forEach(article => {
     article.addEventListener("click", function() {

    let url = window.location,
    path = url.pathname,

      articleID = article.id,
      articlePill = "-Z" + articleID,

      articleRE = /-Z(\w+)/g,

      articles = path.match(articleRE);
    if (!articles) articles = [];

    if (articles.includes(articlePill)) {
      articles = articles.filter(article => article != articlePill);
    } else {
      articles.push(articlePill);
    }

    url.pathname = articles.join("");

  });

});
```

---

### Example:

```js
let url = new URL("http://www.example.com/cyegyufy-ZfirstArticle-ZsecondArticle");
// window.location.pathname

document.querySelectorAll("article").forEach(article => {
  article.addEventListener("click", function() {

    let path = url.pathname,

      articleID = article.id,
      articlePill = "-Z" + articleID,

      articleRE = /-Z(\w+)/g,

      articles = path.match(articleRE);
    if (!articles) articles = [];

    if (articles.includes(articlePill)) {
      articles = articles.filter(article => article != articlePill);
    } else {
      articles.push(articlePill);
    }

    url.pathname = articles.join("");

    console.log(url);

  });

});
```

```css
article {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<article id="firstArticle">
  <h6>firstArticle</h6>
</article>
<article id="secondArticle">
  <h6>secondArticle</h6>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! this is exactly what i needed

Comment: @jahn1228 it's no problem! It was a good question. Let me know if anything needs more explanation!